# ¿Porque no funciona este ThemeData utilizando Cubit Bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

tengo este código con el cual intento cambiar el tema de la app pulsando 2 botones, la aplicación coge correctamente el tema, pero al llamar a las funciones **changeColorTheme** o **changeDarkMode** el theme no cambia y no entiendo exactamente porque (los métodos se llaman correctamente, lo he comprobado), he probado a cambiar el cubit de muchísimas formas, pero aún asi no consigo que cambie, hay algo que no estoy entendiendo en el funcionamiento del cubit o en el funcionamiento del Theme, espero que alguien pueda arrojar algo de luz, un saludo.

### **main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
     BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeCubit(),
      child: const MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
        theme: context.select((ThemeCubit cubit) {
          return cubit.state.themeData;
        }),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routerConfig: appRouter,
        //routerDelegate: appRouter,
        );
  }
}
```

### **theme_cubit.dart**

```
class ThemeCubit extends Cubit<ThemeState> {
  ThemeCubit()
      : super(ThemeState(
          themeData: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ));

  final List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.red,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.orange,
  ];

  bool isDarkMode = false;

  void changeColorTheme(int index) {
    emit(state.copyWith(color: colors[index]));
  }

  void changeDarkMode() {
    isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
    emit(state.copyWith(
      themeData: ThemeData(
        brightness: isDarkMode ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: state.color, // Mantén el color al cambiar de tema
      ),
    ));
    print('$isDarkMode');
  }
}
```

### **theme_state.dart**

```
class ThemeState extends Equatable{
  final ThemeData themeData;
  final Color color;

  const ThemeState({
    required this.themeData,
    required this.color,
  });

  ThemeState copyWith({
    ThemeData? themeData,
    Color? color
}) => ThemeState(
    themeData: themeData ?? this.themeData, 
    color: color ?? this.color
    );
    
    @override
    List<Object?> get props => [themeData, color];
}
```

### **home_screen.dart**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  static String name = 'home-screen';
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeCubit(),
      child: const _HomeScreenView(),
    );
  }
}

class _HomeScreenView extends StatelessWidget {
  const _HomeScreenView();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FilledButton(onPressed: () {
            context.read<ThemeCubit>().changeColorTheme(1);

          } , child: const Text('Rojo')),
          FilledButton(onPressed: (){
            context.read<ThemeCubit>().changeDarkMode();
            
          } , child: const Text('Dark')),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que estás inyectando el bloc dos veces. Una vez en el main y otra en el home.

Cuando inyectas un bloc, estás creando una nueva instancia del mismo, por ende, el bloc inyectado en el main y el bloc inyectado en el home, son completamente diferentes el uno del otro. Has creado dos clases que nada tienen que ver la una con la otra. Por esa razón cuando actualizas el tema, lo haces del cubit que has inyectado en el home, lo cual, no tiene efecto en el cubit que has inyectado en el main.

Te debería funcionar si quitas el blocprovider de home.

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo utilizar provider, se vuelve complejo sin necesidad para solo algunas propiedades. Aunque tambien puedes usar BloC.

Aqui el ejemplo con Provider.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeChanger with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _darkTheme = false;
  ThemeData? _currentTheme;

  bool get darkTheme => this._darkTheme;
  ThemeData get currentTheme => this._currentTheme as ThemeData;

  ThemeChanger(int theme) {
    _currentTheme = ThemeData.light();
    switch(theme) {
      case 1:
        darkTheme   = false;
      break;
      case 2:
        darkTheme   = true;
      break;
      default: 
        darkTheme = false;
        
    }
  }

  set darkTheme(bool value) {
    _darkTheme = value;
    if(value) {
      _currentTheme = ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ).copyWith(
          colorScheme: _currentTheme!.colorScheme.copyWith(
            secondary: Color(0xffFFCA3A),
      ));
    } else {
      _currentTheme = ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
      ).copyWith(
          colorScheme: _currentTheme!.colorScheme.copyWith(
            primary: Colors.purple,
          )
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Y para consumir:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    final appTheme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: appTheme.currentTheme,
        .....
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hola Paolo, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme, se como hacerlo con provider, pero quiero encontrar la forma de hacerlo con Cubit por el simple hecho de saber que es lo que falla realmente y porque no funciona. No encuentro a nadie que consiga hacerlo funcionar! seguiré investigando!